# How to compare string and int as int?

Tags: php, if-statement, compare

```
$a['id'] = 124;
$b['id'] = '124';

if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {}
```

In this case I want id`s are equals. How to properly compare string and int as int?
Is there elegant way?

Comment: Try `if(if ($a['id'] == (int)$b['id']) {}`

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine as it is. https://3v4l.org/d2Oj3

Comment: By the way, your code works fine.

Comment: It works, but I think it is uncorrect way

Comment: @searcherforthetrueth Since you are using `==` instead of `===`, PHP will *automatically* convert the type of the second value as necessary for comparison. What you are doing is fine.

Comment: @Nick thanks for new knowledge! I didn't about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the string value to integer like this:

```
if($a['id'] == (int)$b['id']) {    
    // notice `(int)` which will make the '124' to int 124
}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe is there another elegant way with a trick with php standard function something like `compare('int', value1, value2)`- maybe do you know function like `array_reduce` or something like these fictional examples for correct comparing two values?

Comment: Please just remove inner if condition.its not needed.